# Store the return command in array Shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have to store the return of this command into an array
I tried this :

```
my_array=( $(/sbin/ifconfig | grep 'inet addr:' | cut -d: -f2 | awk '{ print $1}' | grep -v '127.0.0.1'))
```

but it gives me the error below:

> /bin: is a directory

Comment: No reason it should give that error, are you sure it is this line? /bin isn't even mentioned.

Comment: yes there is no directory /bin in my code, I rewrite the code and its ok now

Answer (score 0):

You could remove parenthesis as below. You can also use ip command, its newer version and more powerful than ifconfig.

```
my_array=$(ip addr show  |  grep -Po 'inet \K[\d.]+' | grep -v 127.0.0.1)
```

Answer (score 0):

In my GNU bash 4.4.0(1), ifconfig is not giving me inet addr: but just inet  like this:

> ```
>     inet 10.0.2.15  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.2.255
>     inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
> ```

In any case the error you receive doesn't make sense to me.

I can get the IP address combining grep & awk like this:

```
sbin/ifconfig | grep -v "127.0.0.1" |grep 'inet ' |awk -F" " '{print $2}'
```

(awk -F" " : Field Seperator. Field Seperator in my case is space.)

Also this works for me , due to the fact that 127.0.0.1 goes to the end:

```
/sbin/ifconfig |grep -m1 'inet '| awk -F" " '{print $2}
```

(grep -m1 = stop after first match)

PS: If you have plans to append your array , you need to use my_array+=(...)